sqlachemy save existing model in new session
I've retrieved instance by orm and changes it's field. But I wonder, how to insert updates in new session. I'd like to save updated instance of table row
def save(obj: Model):
  with session_context() as session:
    # what to do?

Nothing tried, I'm newbie in sqlalchemy
